# How to conditionally load applications in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I am running two applications in a tomcat instance by placing two sub-directories in webapps directory. This is working fine for me. 
I have a new requirement to conditionally load the second application and the condition can be based on a value written in one of the file present in the system (outside the webapps directory structure). 
This needs to be done dynamically means I don't have the flexibility of moving the one directory out from webapps directory.
Is there a way to add some script to attain the same? Any other way?

### More details:

I have spring scheduler code (so application starts automatically) running in the other tomcat application which I want to prevent from execution and I want to avoid adding the check in the spring scheduler code (which I mentioned above) as that is opensource and the check will be required in many places so I am thinking of letting tomcat not load the second application. Also this code is a firmware code where I need to have this behavior on tomcat startup (via systemctl)

Comment: Do you understand that in the Servlet architecture, your web app is not invoked if no incoming requests arrive?

Comment: Tomcat allows starting/stopping any application, for example by using the [manager application](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Start_an_Existing_Application). You can also use JMX to connect and do the same. It's not exactly an answer to your question, you will need to script around.

Comment: You can write a global filter and custom default servlet inside tomcat/conf/web.xml, and prevent calls going to a particular pattern, otherwise you need to archive this via reverse proxy only, disable all your servlets from auto-start on boot